# First triangle does not render after using GLSL-shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm currently learning OpenGL (and GLSL) from this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/). So far I made it to Tutorial 2: The First Triangle. My code is a bit different since I'm more comfortable programming C, instead of the more common C++. Also, I used glfw3 to open my window, where the tutorial uses glfw, I believe. As for now I've been able to write everything in C, and everything worked til the point where I used my first shaders. Whenever i use them, my triangle wont render. I'm on a Mac and I haven't had the time to upgrade to OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) and therefore I'm forced to use OpenGL 3.2 and GLSL 1.2.

tl;dr: problem: My triangle will not render whenever I use the shaders.

Here's my code:

```
int main(void) {
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if(!glfwInit()) {
    return -1;
}

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Tutorial 1", NULL, NULL);
if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

/* Initialize GLEW */
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; // Needed in core profile
if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

/* Triangle's vertices */
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

// This will identify our vertex buffer
GLuint vertexbuffer;
// Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
// The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
// Give our vertices to OpenGL.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders("VertexShader.txt", "FragmentShader.txt");

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    /* Render here */
    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

And here is my VertexShader:

```
#version 120
vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

My FragmentShader:

```
#version 120
vec3 color;

void main() {
    color = vec3(1, 0, 0);
}
```

I think it might have something to do with shadersfiles, I think I might have translated them wrong from the tutorial (he uses GLSL 3.3).

Comment: @AntonD: actually, as he is using version 1.20, it would be `attribute`. Also, the output of the fragment shader is not correctly declared.

Comment: @derhass So what is actually wrong with the output of my fragment shader, I know I can't use out vec3 color, because that's a later version according to some of the sites I've been on.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman's answer explains all what is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main things that are wrong with your shaders and the crux of the problem boils down to how you are declaring the variables intended for shader input and output.

In your vertex shader, you have an input: **`vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace`**

- Using GLSL 1.20 syntax this should be `attribute vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace`.

In your fragment shader you have an output: **`vec3 color`** <sub>(which would be `out vec3 color` in a GLSL 3.30 tutorial)</sub>

- You cannot declare arbitrary variables as fragment shader outputs in GLSL 1.20, you have to use `gl_FragColor` or if you want to output to a specific draw buffer: `gl_FragData [n]`.

  <sup>Side note: Never mix and match the two.</sup>

---

#### Corrected Vertex Shader:

```
 #version 120
 attribute vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

 //in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
 //^^ It was probably written this way in the GLSL 3.30 tutorial

 void main() {
   gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
   gl_Position.w = 1.0;
 }
```

#### Corrected Fragment Shader:

```
 #version 120
 //out vec3 color; -- DO NOT DO THIS IN GLSL 1.20

 void main() {
   //color = vec3(1, 0, 0);
   gl_FragColor = vec4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 }
```

---

On a final note, you have to match the attribute binding location to your attribute pointer location. Since GLSL 1.20 does not support `layout` qualifiers the best way to do this would be to add an additional line of code to your program:

```
glBindAttribLocation (programID, 0, "vertexPosition_modelspace");
```

Comment: Alright, I updated my shaders, and I placed the additional function between the part where I link my program and where I attach the shaders (if I understand the reference correclty) but still it won't show me the red triangle. Am I doing things right? Or do I need glGetAttribLocation() to retrieve my index?

Comment: @Meastroman: Wait, are you saying you link your program before attaching your shaders? You should compile your shaders, attach them, bind attrib locations and then link. I would suggest you look into `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)` and `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` while you are at it - the GLSL compiler and linker will generate useful error and warning logs just like any normal compiler.

Comment: No sorry that's not what I meant, I attach them first before I link. But I suddenly got a WARNING saying: "Could not find vertex shader attribute 'vertexPosition_modelspace' to match BindAttributeLocation request." So right now I'm trying to fix that :P I hope I will see my red triangle once I figured this out.

Comment: Finally I managed to fix my problem, I had 2 versions of both of my shaders, and when I was done editing I forgot to use vertexShader2.txt and fragmentShader2.txt. But thanks for the help and explaination about GLSL